# Protobuf, MapStruct and null values

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, mapstruct

Given this proto

```
option java_outer_classname = "FooProto";
message Foo {
    string bar = 1;
}
```

This java class:

```
public class MyFoo {
    String bar;
}
```

And this Mapper (using Mapstruct):

```
@Mapper
public interface FooMapper() {
    FooProto.Foo toProtoFoo(MyFoo myFoo);
}
```

When I have an instance of MyFoo with a null bar and I try to map it to the proto I get a NullPointerException.

This is because the auto-generated code for the Mapper invokes an auto-generated method for the proto that looks like:

```
public Builder setBar(java.lang.String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    bar_ = value;
    onChanged();
    return this;
}
```

Is there any way of avoiding this problem? (that does not involve sanitizing MyFoo instance before mapping so that it has no null values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a different `NullValueCheckStrategy`.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface FooMapper() {
    FooProto.Foo toProtoFoo(MyFoo myFoo);
}
```

This will always do a `null` check before invoking `setBar`

Have a look at [Controlling checking result for `null` properties in bean mapping](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#checking-source-property-for-null-arguments) for more info.